# What token should I use while sending email when I am programmatically adding the content?

Tags: forms, rules, emails, tokens

When I fill the [form](http://etraining.esc.rl.ac.uk/node/add/event). I get this email

> A new Event "Event name" has been created. To approve this Event
>   please go to http://websitename.com/content/content-name and click
>   ‘publish’.

I have set this in the [rules](https://drupal.org/project/rules) to send an email which is this.

> A new [node:content-type] [node:title] has been created To approve
>   this [node:content-type] please go to [node:url] and click ‘publish’.

But the problem is, for some contents, I don't want to fill the form, as I am using programmatic way to add content. I use this code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors','1');
ini_set('memory_limit', '512M');
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
include_once './includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node = new stdClass();
$title                =  "This is the Title of the Content";  
// $summary            =   "summarry";//$_POST['summary'];      
$body                  =  "This is testing of body section of Automated Script";// $_POST['body']; 
  $node->uid      = '0'; //author
  $node->type     = 'event';    //content type
  // $node->created  = time() - (rand( 1,240) * 60); 
  $node->created  = strtotime("now");
  $node->changed  = strtotime("now");
  $node->status   = 0;
  $node->promote  = 0;
  $node->sticky   = 0;
  $node->language = 'und'; // undefined
// $node->body['und'][0]['summary'] = $summary;
  // Body Format
  $node->body['format']  = 'full_html';

  // Title
  $node->title = $title;
  // Body
  $node->body['und'][0]['value']   = $body;
  // City
  $node->field_location['und'][0] =  array('value' => 'Oxford');
  // Country
  $node->taxonomy_vocabulary_6['und'][0] = array('tid' => 10921); 
  // Research Community
  $node->taxonomy_vocabulary_7['und'][0] = array('tid' => 16069);
  // Project/Organisation
  $node->taxonomy_vocabulary_8['und'][0] = array('tid' => 16126);
  /*
   * 10921, 16069, 16126 are the IDs of the the taxonomy terms.
   */
  // Date
  $node->field_event_date['und'][0] =  array(
      // The start date.
      'value' => '2014-04-05T10:00:00',
      // The end date.
      'value2' => '2014-04-06T11:00:00',
  );
  // Duration
  $node->field_duration['und'][0] =  array('value' => '2');
  // Email
  $node->field_user_email['und'][0] =  array('email' => 'exampleemail@gmail.com');
  // Event Link
  $node->field_url['und'][0] = array('url'  => "https://www.google.com");
  // Number of Places
  $node->field_people_expected['und'][0] =  array('value' => '25');

node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
print "ok";
?>
```

**PROBLEM HERE:**
When I add content using this method. I get this email.

> A new Event "Event name" has been created. To approve this Event
>   please go to `http://./content/content-name` and click ‘publish’.

Instead of website name, it shows only a "." (dot). How to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `[node:url:absolute]`?

Comment: yeah, I just tried it and it still gives the same. No change.

Comment: And what is `[site:url]/[node:url]` doing?

Comment: `[site:url]` gave this `please go to http://./ and click ‘publish’` and I was already using `[node:url]` which gives me this `http://./content/content-name`